# Pass Cancellation Token to child thread

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, parallel.for

I have scenario where I create a cancellation token that passed to parent thread, I need to pass same cancellation token to child thread. But when I pass cancellation token to child thread, threads are not cancelled when parent invokes Cancel().

```
public void main()
{
   CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
   CancellationToken token = cts.Token;
   ChildClass instance = new ChildClass();

   Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() => instance.start(token), token), token);
}

public void cancel()
{
    cts.Cancel();
}

public class ChildClass()
{
    public void start(CancellationToken token)
    {
        ParallelOptions po = new ParallelOptions();
        po.CancellationToken = token;

        Parallel.For(0, 10, i => 
              {"do some processing"}, po, i);
    } 
}
```

I have created a cancellation token in parent class and passing it to child thread through parallel options, but threads created by Parallel.For are not terminated when parent invokes Cancel().

Is there a concept of passing CancellationToken as reference?

Comment: Where are you calling Cancel()? Is `ChildClass` a class or a method?

Comment: Added snippet to invoke cancel(), this is a windows service, so cancel() method will be invoked on receiving cancel event from system.

ChildClass is a class.

Comment: if (token.IsCancellationRequested == true)...

Comment: I'd say that passing CancellationTokenSource is a fundamental concept of thread programming, from v4.0 onwards. If you find that closures don't work with `Parallel.For()`, I'm wondering, is that because you're not evaluating the `token.IsCancellationRequested`? I also don't see any `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested` in your sample code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing inherently wrong with how you're using CancellationTokenSource. You just don't know that the task is cancelled because you're not using `Wait` to handle the `TaskCanceledException`. When `Main` is this:

```
CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
CancellationToken token = cts.Token;
ChildClass instance = new ChildClass();

var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() => instance.start(token), token), token);
cts.Cancel();
task.Wait();
```

You would see the exceptions.

Here's a full example of `Parallel.For` being canceled:

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var instance = new ChildClass();

        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() => instance.start(cts.Token)).Wait());
        cts.Cancel();
        task.Wait();
    }
}

public class ChildClass
{
    public void start(CancellationToken token)
    {
        var parallelOptions = new ParallelOptions {CancellationToken = token};
        try
        {
            Parallel.For(0, 100000, parallelOptions, i =>
            {
                // Do something
            });
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("canceled");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

> canceled

Comment: I have tried with task.WaitAll(), but child threads created by Parallel.For are not cancelled.

Comment: @VarunGupta they are, I added a complete example.

Comment: Yes, this works and thanks for your response. The issue I am facing is that I have a windows service and in OnStop method, I invoke cts.Cancel(). Here is does not invoke OperationCancelledException, any reason why?

Comment: @VarunGupta Either the operation actually ended already, and the code is stuck on something else, or there is an exception but it's inside a task that you don't await/wait for.

Comment: My Foreach loop is still running, and in OnStop I call cts.Cancel. If I add a condition parallelOptions.CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested then code goes through it but the OperationCancelledException in not called.

Comment: On waiting for tasks in OnStop after invoking cts.Cancel, I see code reaching to OperationCancelledException for foreach loop.

Comment: @VarunGupta I can't understand if you have a problem or not. You do get an `OperationCancelledException`?

Comment: I had a problem previously but after using Task.Wait() after invoking cts.Cancel() in OnStop Method, issue is resolved. :)